# Why does JFrame begin to lag after the frame is open for some time?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, graphics2d

I'm trying to develop a game from scratch. I'm making a grid to hold different characters and then have a different class render those characters. The problem I'm encountering is that `JFrame` begins to lag. At first, the character is responsive but it begins to lag quickly. The lag gets worse and worse as the program stays open.

I have no idea where to begin to start to solve this problem.

```
package game;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class runner extends JPanel {

    static MyKeyListener list;
    static player play;
    static grid gameGrid;
    static int size = 600;

    public runner() {
        MyKeyListener listener = new MyKeyListener(this);

        player one = new player(5, 4);
        grid Grid = new grid(10, 10, size, one);
        play = one;
        gameGrid = Grid;
        list = listener;
        this.addKeyListener(listener);
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        runner runn = new runner();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("game");
        int frameSize = size + (size / 2);
        frame.setSize(size, size);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(runn);
        frame.addKeyListener(list);
        boolean isRunning = true;
        while (isRunning) {
            drawingComponent DC = gameGrid.update();
            if (list.getDir() == 1) {
                gameGrid.moveUp(play, play.getX(), play.getY());
                list.setDir(0);
            }
            if (list.getDir() == 2) {
                gameGrid.moveDown(play, play.getX(), play.getY());
                list.setDir(0);
            }
            if (list.getDir() == 3) {
                gameGrid.moveLeft(play, play.getX(), play.getY());
                list.setDir(0);
            }
            if (list.getDir() == 4) {
                gameGrid.moveRight(play, play.getX(), play.getY());
                list.setDir(0);
            }
            frame.add(DC);
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    }

    public player getPlayer() {
        return play;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe because you're flooding the Event Queue with more operations then the Event Dispatching Thread can handle; Maybe because you're violating the single threaded nature of the API by updating the UI outside of the EDT; May a bunch of other reasons which are available in your code example

Comment: Many things to correct here, but especially that tight game loop that completely ignores Swing threading rules. Get rid of all static modifiers other than for the main method, and use a Swing Timer to drive the animation, not a `while (isRunning)` uncontrollable loop.

Comment: You should probably learn the basics of Java before tackling something like this. There are many features of Java besides graphics that will make your task easier.  Here's a quick tip.  If `list.getDir() == 1` it isn't going to equal `2, 3, or 4` so you might want to use if/else constructs.  Caveat.  Unless you're using threads which opens up an even larger can of worms.

Comment: Please use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: First of all in **OOP** don't use loop like this. Try implementing `KeyListener`.

Comment: One more thing use intended thread, don't create you own, `Swing` isn't thread friendly., read more about `invokelater()`